# Derivate of a complex function

Tags: partial-derivative

I found in a paper the folowing derivative:

$$\frac{\partial f(X(\theta),\theta)}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\partial f(X(\theta),\theta)}{\partial X(\theta)}\frac{\partial X(\theta)}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial f(X(\theta),\theta)}{\partial \theta}$$

How they get this derivative?

Comment: As a general question, is there a rule that discussion on this site must be in English? And if so, what is the logical base of that?

Comment: @WhatsUp Most participants here are native speakers of English and much mathematics world wide is in English so as a general rule questions in English are more likely to reach readers who can help. In this case the original French title was pretty easy to figure out and the question itself was in English.

Comment: @EthanBolker *Most participants here are native speakers of English* Are there statistical data supporting this claim? Also according to my knowledge, French is a non-negligible language in the world of mathematics. That said, I'm fine with discussing in English, but I just find it unfair that sometimes questions in other languages get downvoted or closed, regardless of the mathematical contents.

Answer (score 0):

This is bad notation. It could instead be written as

$$g(\theta)=f(X(\theta),\theta)$$

$$g'(\theta)=f^{(1,0)}(X(\theta),\theta)\cdot X'(\theta)+f^{(0,1)}(X(\theta),\theta)$$

where $f^{(p,q)}$ denotes a partial derivative of $f$. This is the multivariable chain rule.

See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2906858/472818).

Answer (score 0):

You combine the way you differentiate a function of two variables with the chain rule.

I find it best to explain this with differentials (others may disagree, and provide another answer with a rigorous proof).

If you have a function $f(x,y)$ of two variables and want to know how small changes in $x$ and $y$ cause $f$ to change you calculate

$$
df  = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx
+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy
$$

Then if each of $x$ and $y$ depends on some parameter $t$ you know
$$
\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt}
+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt} .
$$

You can see how your (confusingly written) expression matches this pattern. There the dependence of the second variable on the parameter is simply $y = t$ so $dy/dt = 1$.