# What is the partial derivative of G(uz,u) with respect to u.

Tags: calculus

Suppose $G(z,u)$ with $u,z \in \mathbb{R}$ is a two variable function.  Is there some "chain rule like" formula that will give me $\frac{\partial G(uz,u) }{\partial u}$ in terms of say $\frac{\partial G(z,u) }{\partial u}$ and/or $\frac{\partial G(z,u) }{\partial z}$.

Comment: The partial derivative notation is not well suited to this type of problem. Does $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ mean that $z$ is held fixed while $u$ varies, or that $uz$ is held fixed while $u$ varies? Instead, I suggest the notation $G^{(1,0)}$ and $G^{(0,1)}$ for the partial derivatives of $G$, and maybe $H(x,y)=G(yx,y)$ for the function you want to differentiate. Note that these are just functions from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$, and it doesn't matter what the variables are called.

Comment: Amyway, yes there's a multivariable chain rule: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/chainrule.aspx

Comment: I said almost the same thing about 2 years ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2906858/472818